# Polynomial functions/basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

If I suppose $R \subset F$ and have polynomial functions $p_{k,j} : F \to F$ by

$p_{1,0}(x)=(x-2)^3$

$p_{2,0}(x)=(x-1)$

$p_{2,1}(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$

$p_{2,2}(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^2$

and the polynomial function $p: F \to F$ given by $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^3$.  I have shown that $\{p_{1,0}, p_{2,0}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}\}$ is a basis for polynomial functions from $F$ to $F$ of degree three or less by showing there are non-zero $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_n$ s.t. $\alpha_0 p_{1,0}+\cdots+\alpha_3 p_{2,2}=0$.  I'm struggling with how to express function $f_0(x)=1$ and $f_1(x)=x$ in this basis.  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that it should be written “there are **no** non-zero” instead of “there are non-zero”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Considering the coefficients at the powers of $x$ in the equality $\beta_0 p_{1,0}+....+\beta_3 p_{2,2}=f_1$
transform it into a system of linear equations.

Also I remark that $f_1=f_0+p_{2,0}$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it